# Reviewing Reviews: they aren't displaying the content as it existed at the time of the review

Tags: discussion, support, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I understand the wording here is odd, but I've noticed the following and can't tell if it's a bug or not.

1. Someone proposes an edit, I thought it was way too minor ( they changed ONE character and left a plethora of issues), and I didn't feel like fixing all the errors.
2. Robo-approvers approver the edit anyhow
3. I look back later after I noticed a pattern of similar behavior and edit the post to make all of the fixes myself
4. **This is the fun one** When I look at the 'proposed' edit that should have been rejected by the other reviewers, it display the latest content aside from the literal change the user had proposed...  **as in it has all of my improvements in it now**

This is problematic because someone looks at that edit, and says "there was nothing else for him to fix." Well of course not, it looks much better when I've cleaned up everything else...

What's going on here?

Here's an instance of it: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8284518

compare to 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30583610/revisions

Comment: Hm. But consider that you do the edits BEFORE the reviews. If the reviewers then see the old version like you propose should be the case here, they're going to base their vote on what is no longer the truth. That to me seems a far worse scenario than what you are describing now.

Comment: Except you got it wrong. I did the edit AFTER the reviews.  The review page should show the data as it existed at the time someone reviewed it; with the delta THEY saw. Period.  Otherwise you have no idea what you are looking at later.
If i did the edit before the reviews; there wouldn't have been a review to do because it would have been bypassed by my edit.

Comment: Yes I see, I messed up the order of events. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That seems a particular side effect from the "suggested editor" only changing the title of the of the original post.

I just reviewed a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8286585) and changed the **body** of the post with a [further change](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30586822/7) (making the post start with "How can I..") and that change is not shown when retrieving the suggested edit review.

It would be interested to see what happened if you further edited the title of the post you linked to.